# Transferring files from one Kindle to another with a forgotten password

Tags: kindle-fire

My cousin has recently got a new Kindle Fire HDX and she wants to transfer onto it all her books and music from her older Kindle HD (smaller than the newer Kindle, but in all other respects they look the same). Unfortunately she cant remember the password for the older Kindle.

Being the family IT "expert" Ive been given this problem to solve, however I have never used a Kindle before. After some searching about on the web, it seems to me I just need to log into the new Kindle with the same account (xxx@kindle.com) and password as the old one, and then select Archive and download all the books etc. from the cloud.

However, not knowing the password to this original kindle poses problems. Looking on the Kindle Support section of the Amazon website it seems there is no password recovery option - you have to reset the Kindle, wiping everything off it, to be able to set a new password.

Is my understanding of this all correct?

Is there a better / simpler way of transferring all the books and music from the old Kindle to the new one?

I just wanted to get some advice off somebody who is more knowledgeable than me on Kindles before I start wiping devices and the realizing I made a terrible mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is all of the content on the old device from Amazon?

Comment: Yes, everything on the old Kindle got bought from Amazon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about accessing the old kindle. Everything purchased through amazon remains available from the cloud. Presumably your cousin used the same Amazon account to purchase both kindles.  Just log on and send it to the new kindle.

If not, go to amazon.com click sign in and than go through the forgotten password process for the original Amazon account. The password for the old kindle may be different and does not matter, it is only the account that matters.

Once you have access to both accounts, you will need to transfer the new kindle to ownership of the old account. Then you will be able to download to from the cloud as you learned in your earlier research.

Alternatively you can keep the accounts separate, after you have accessed the old account, you can download to the PC and transfer to the new kindle, but this will only work for non-DRM works.  DRM works will be restricted to devices registered to the original account.

Comment: It goes without saying that this all hinges on accessing the original account, if you can't do that, it is pretty much game over....

Comment: Found the original password in the end, so I got into the original account and everything was easy from there! Thanks for your help - I'm going to mark this as correct for any others who have similar problems.